Items, background, and start menu missing while running Cinnamon on Remote Desktop
I'm trying to run Cinnamon using RDP on a WSL Ubuntu enviroment. I've properly configured the .xsessions file and xrdp, however, even after managing to make it work, the display is blank, only showing the taskbar and the date, every window works, and I can access all of the apps, but it becomes confusing trying to navigate without any icons.
One thing I noticed is that whenever I enter the remote desktop for the first time (after rebooting) it prints the current message on a popup.

Problems during Cinnamon startup
Cinnamon started successfully, but one or more applets, desklets or extensions failed to load.  
Check your system log and the Cinnamon LookingGlass log for any issues. You can disable the offending extension(s) in Cinnamon Settings to prevent this message from occurring. Please contact the developer.

I do not know how to access these logs, I've been told it can be accessed through these commands: 
cat ~/.xsession-errors or for the old versions
cat ~/.cinnamon/glass.log 
None of them worked. After revisiting some guides, I didn't find anything useful. If it helps, I'll show my .xsession and my startwm.sh files.
.xsession
cinnamon-session-cinnamon

startwm.sh
if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile
fi

# test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
# exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
cinnamon

If there's anything I can show to help, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.
